# jTextField text automatically set to previous state after clicking ok in JOption pane

Tags: java

initially text is set to every jtextfield on formActivatedEvent. when i clear the textfields and try login it usually
gives an JOption pane error message. afer clicking ok in joptionpane previous text automatically set to every textfield.how to avoid this.
my english is very bad.hope you understand.i've youtubed( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QoktSV7U1vI&feature=youtu.be ) the this problem.please can anyone help me?

Comment: remove text by setText("");

Answer (score 0):

What I can see from the link is that you autoset the textfield to clear with this command that's bold in the code below

......

```
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Wrong password or accout disbled);

  **JTextField.setText('');** // To achieve what you have described this line is to be omitted


  .........
```